# C++ Error when trying to store the reverse of an already existing array into another array. Can't use pointers

Tags: c++

```
//Function to store the reverse of original array   
     void ReverseName(char name[], char reverse[]) {
            int i, j = 0;
            for (i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++) {} //loop to find size of name
            for (i; i >= 0; i--) {              //loop to go backwards from end of name    
                reverse[j] = name[i];           //should get stored here
                j++;                       //run through array and populate it
            }
        }
```

It seems like the code isn't copying properly and the output is coming out blank. When I put a 'cout' to check name[], it detects and prints it no problem in reverse, the problem is the copying into another array.

Comment: What will be the first character you copy? And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This presents an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Simply use your debugger to figure out the following two questions, and you will immediately figure out why your code is not working: 1) after the first loop terminates, what is the value of `name[i]`. 2) And what becomes the value of `reverse[0]`. Once you learn how to use your debugger, and use it to tell you what the answers to these two questions are, you should be able to immediately figure out your bug all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start the second loop with the index of the `'\0'` in `i`, so the reversed string will have `'\0'` in the first character and thus seem empty.

Replace this:

```
for (i; i >= 0; i--)
```

with:

```
while (i--)
```

After the second loop finishes, terminate the string:

```
reverse[j] = '\0';
```